# How do I force MyEclipse to hot-deploy a JavaScript file to my JBoss instance?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, jboss, myeclipse

I'm having trouble with MyEclipse 7.1.1 hot-deployment of files to my JBoss 4 server.

The problem is this: while my server is running, I can make changes to various JAVA and HTML files, which are then hot-deployed immediately (I can see the changes reflected in my browser when I refresh the page). However, while working on a particular JavaScript file, my changes are not being hot-deployed. This makes it very difficult to work on and debug this file, since I have to stop my server, redeploy, and start it again each time I make changes. This is a new problem - it didn't used to happen with this file, so I think something got screwed up in my MyEclipse configuration.

I've verified that my projects (JBoss 4 instances) are all set up in "Exploded" mode for hot-deployment.

I'm also 99% sure that this isn't an issue with my browser, since I always refresh with CTRL+F5, and I've tried a number of things like clearing my browser cache to get the currently deployed version of the file.

I've also tried doing a "clean" on the project while the server is running, and that didn't force a deployment either.

Any sort of solution would be helpful. I'd love for MyEclipse to deploy the file automatically, but I'm also open to manually forcing hot-deployment of this particular file while I work on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with both IE and the application caching strategy.

The following fixed it:

1. Setting a GZIP compression environment variable to be OFF. This way the GZIP compressed JS files are not cached for two weeks.
2. Setting IE8 to "check for newer versions of stored pages every time I visit the webpage", and using CTRL+F5 to refresh (as before).

Answer (score 0):

```
   var dwScriptFileUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + appName + '/extend.js?' + Math.random();
   var dwDOM = document.all('myiframe0').contentWindow.document;
var dwScript = dwDOM.createElement("script");
dwScript.type = "text/javascript";
dwScript.src = dwScriptFileUrl;
dwDOM.body.appendChild(dwScript);
```